# Putnam Challenge Question

Tags: calculus, geometry, contest-math, area, curves

> Determine all real numbers $a$, where $a>0$, for which there exists a nonnegative continuous function $f(x)$, defined on $[0,a]$ with the property that the region $$R=\big\{(x,y)\,\big|\, 0\le x\le a\text{ and } 0\le y\le f(x)\big\}$$ has perimeter $k$ units and area $k$ units for some real number of $k$.

I apologize for not yet knowing how to type equations as they are seen in most questions on this forum. I joined about 15 minutes ago.

Comment: This will help you get started writing equations and all things math related. http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: my first guess would be $a\geq 4$. For $a=4$ take $f(x)=4$ and perimeter and area are the same. for larger $a$ you can still take the cube and enlargen the perimeter, but i didnt find a method for $a<4$ yet nor a proof

Comment: Is $k$ some fixed value, and we have to find all $a$ for a given $k$, or is the question to find all $a$ such that there is a $k$ such that the conditions hold?

Comment: From my understanding of the problem, $k$ can vary. It's simply that the perimeter and area of the the rectangle formed on the plane by $x$ and $f(x)$ have to remain equal from $[0,a]$ of some continuous function.

Comment: Doing some simple algebra with those given requirements, might help us put some restrictions on what can and can't be an input.

Comment: $xy=2x+2y$ leads to $y= frac/(2x)(x-2)$

Comment: Some one show mercy and help me turn that into an actual fraction.

Comment: My thought process is that area and perimeter of the region $R$ cannot be equal for $x>2$, (such inputs make our non-negative function negative) and if the region $R$ must span from $$[0,a]$ while retaining this property then there are no real positive numbers that $a$ could be.

Comment: I dare not mention the horrible fate our "continuous" function meets when $x=2$ Again this is nothing but me playing around with the logic. I highly doubt Putnam would pose this question if it had no solution.

Comment: $\frac{2x}{x-2}=$ \frac{2x}{x-2}

Comment: Which gives an easy solution for $a>2$. $f_a(x)=\frac{2a}{a-2}$

Comment: My previous comments talk about the problems I have with that answer. It has to retain the area/perimeter property as well as remain non negative for all of $[a,0]$. That's impossible after you plug in values less than 2 inot that function, as the outputs are negative.

Comment: The function given is a constant function in $x$. so for $a>2$ it is non-negative for $[0,a]$. This means it yields an answer for $a>2$

Comment: Correct me if i am wrong. $R$ is defined as the region bounded by $x$ and $f(x)$. So a constant function would have the same height throughout, but vary in length. Area and Perimeter are only equal when $x=a$ in the equation you gave.

Comment: Okay, now i think i got the point where we differ.

What i do is take any $a>2$ and try to create a solution for it. The formula you provided is really helpfull for this. 

so let $a>2$ then define $f_a(x)=\frac{2a}{a-2}$ note that it is constant in $x$, but gives a different result for every $a$ and is welldefined and non-negative because $a>2$.

Perimeter: $f_a(0)+f_a(a)+2a=\frac{4a}{a-2}+2a=\frac{4a+2a^2-4a}{a-2}=\frac{2a^2}{a-2}$

Area: $f_a(0)a=\frac{2a^2}{a-2}$

Does this make it clear?

Comment: I understand now, and i apologize for the confusion. Up votes from me.

Answer (score 3):

We first claim that $a>2$ must be satisfied for such a function $f$ to exist.  Suppose that $f:[0,a]\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ satisfies the condition that the perimeter $\sigma$ of $R=\big\{(x,y)\in [0,a]\times \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}\,\big|\,y\leq f(x)\big\}$ equals its area $$\alpha:=\displaystyle \int_0^a\,f(x)\,\text{d}x\,.$$

Write $m$ for the maximum value of $f$ in the interval $[0,a]$ (which exists as $f$ is continuous and $[0,a]$ is a compact space).  Let $c\in[0,a]$ be such that $f(c)=m$.  Then,
$$\sigma \geq a+f(0)+f(a)+\sqrt{c^2+\big(m-f(0)\big)^2}+\sqrt{(a-c)^2+\big(m-f(a)\big)^2}\,.$$
Using the Triangle Inequality, we get that
$$\begin{align}\sigma &\geq a+f(0)+f(a) +\sqrt{\big(c+(a-c)\big)^2+\Big(\big(m-f(0)\big)+\big(m-f(a)\big)\Big)^2}\\
&\geq a+f(0)+f(a)+\sqrt{a^2+\big(2m-f(0)-f(a)\big)^2}\\
&>a+f(0)+f(a)+\big(2m-f(0)-f(a)\big)=a+2m>2m\,.
\end{align}$$

On the other hand, we see that
$$\alpha \leq \int_0^a\,m\,\text{d}x=am\,.$$
Because $\alpha=\sigma$, we conclude that
$$am\geq \alpha = \sigma>2m\text{ or }a>2\,,$$
since $m$ is clearly a positive real number.

To finish the proof, we shall now verify that, when $\alpha>2$, such a function $f$ exists.  As discovered in the comment section, the constant function $f$ defined via $$f(x)=\frac{2a}{a-2}\text{ for all }x\in[0,a]$$ has the required property (with $k=\dfrac{2a^2}{a-2}$).